Simultaneous access to the file by many computers from VSTO
I have about 20 comps using my VSTO add-in in MS Word working in local network.
I have to write some statistic from this machines in one xml file common for all of them placeed in shared folder.
How can I approach this simply but correctly if I know that they will definitely try to access the file at the same time?
I know, that database/queue propably will be the best (I don't have experience), but first I'am looking for solution on file system.
I also wouldn't want to stop working while waiting for the file to be accessed (I don't have experience with async functions too)?
Do you have any suggestion or C# code snippet?

If multiple processes open the file for writing then they will overwrite each other.  That's assuming the file system would allow it (which would be unlikley), in which case you will receive errors.   You need to have 1 application responsible for writing to the file, and all the other applications send requests to that one.  Maybe via messaging bus for example.

You can use some logging library (like NLog), logging libraries handle concurrent file write access properly (even from multiple processes)
If you want to do it yourself, you can use try-catch strategy when writing to a file. If you get shared access exception when logging, you just retry after a bit. If you need a code snippet, you can ask GPT, it's smart enough to provide that.
But even better, you put statistics where it belongs instead of XML files. You don't do XML files for usage statistics in 2024. I mean, use something more reasonable like Azure App Insights for example - you automatically get a nice charts and reports for your statistics, all for free.
